# Validation error message isn't showing in django

Tags: django, django-forms

The validation error **Password not matched** isn't showing if I separately access the fields like `{{form.psrd}}` **(password field)** and `{{form.rpsrd}}` **(Re-Type password field)**. But error message shows if I use `{{form.as_p}}`.

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class formdata(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}))
    psrd = forms.CharField(min_length=8, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'input'}), label='Password')
    rpsrd = forms.CharField(min_length=8, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
                            label='Re-Type Password')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        p = self.cleaned_data['psrd']
        rp = self.cleaned_data['rpsrd']

        if p != rp:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password not matched')
```

Body of regi.html :

```
<body>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <label>
            <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR NAME</p>
            {{form.name}}
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </label>

        <label>
            <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR EMAIL</p>
            {{form.email}}
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </label>

        <label>
            <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</p>
            {{form.psrd}}
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </label>

        <label>
            <p class="label-txt">RE-ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</p>
            {{form.rpsrd}}
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </label>

        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) explains on rendering form manually, you need to add two more tags:

`{{ form.non_field_errors }}` For errors not coming from explicit fields

and `{{ form.field.errors }}` for field errors. So in your template:

```
 <label>
            <p class="label-txt">RE-ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</p>
            {{ form.rpsrd }}
            {% if form.rpsrd.errors %}
                <div class="error">{{ form.rpsrd.errors }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="line-box">
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
```